# How to use REGEX with multiline

Tags: python, regex

The following expression works well extracting the portion of `data` string that starts with the word `Block` followed by open bracket `{` and ending with the closing bracket '}':

```
data ="""
Somewhere over the rainbow
Way up high 
Block {
 line 1
 line 2
 line 3
}
And the dreams that you dreamed of
Once in a lullaby
"""
regex = re.compile("""(Block\ {\n\ [^\{\}]*\n}\n)""", re.MULTILINE)
result = regex.findall(data)
print result
```

which returns:

```
['Block {\n line 1\n line 2\n line 3\n}\n']
```

But if there is another curly bracket inside of the Block portion of the string the expression breaks returning an empty list:

```
data ="""
Somewhere over the rainbow
Way up high 
Block {
 line 1
 line 2
 {{}
 line 3
}
And the dreams that you dreamed of
Once in a lullaby
Block {
 line 4
 line 5
 {{
 }
 line 6
}
Somewhere over the rainbow
Blue birds fly
And the dreams that you dreamed of
Dreams really do come true ooh oh
"""
```

How to modify this regex expression to make it ignore the brackets that are inside of the Blocks and yet each block is returned as the separate entity in `result` list (so each Block could be accessed separately)?

Comment: Actually `[^{}]*` prevents to match any opening curly bracket. Note that the MULTILINE flag isn't what you think. *(it isn't for matching strings that spread over several lines, it only changes the meaning of anchors `^` and `$`. To allow the dot to match newlines, the flag is DOTALL)*

Comment: Since you edited your question: this problem can't be solved with the re module, you need the *regex* module that handles recursion. Note that you need to choose a default behaviour for undetermined cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this work?

`regex = re.compile("""(Block\ {\n\ [^\}]*\n}\n)""", re.MULTILINE)`

In the version you've posted, it is exiting the match whenever it comes across a second opening brace, even though you want it to exit upon the first closing brace.  If you want nested opening / closing braces that's another story.

Comment: Your expression will return an empty list if there is an internal bracket is `}` To illustrate it I have modified my code a bit to include `{{}` inside of the Block.

Comment: What specifically closes the block? `\n\}\n`?

Comment: Yes, the block is always closed with `\n\}\n`. And it always begins with `Block\ {\n`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use:

```
(Block ?{\n ?[^$]+?\n}\n)
```

Since python matches *greedy*, we use *?* to be non-greedy.

Worked well for me. 
In addition I would recommend you the use of https://regex101.com/

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But your expression returns both blocks as a single entity in a list. It only consider the first bracket and the last bracket.

Comment: With your modifications this works well:
    (Block ?{\n ?[^$]+?\n}\n)